# Airflow taskinstance marks task as success but local_task_job says task exited with return code 1

Tags: docker, task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

My Problem:

I am running Airflow using Docker. When I run a task in my DAG the logs show it marked as success but then also show the task as having exited with a return code of 1

What I tried:

- I tried increasing the amount of memory allocated to my containers
- I removed email on failure logic from my DAG

My DAG

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

"""
### Tutorial Documentation
Documentation that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located
[here](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html)
"""
# [START tutorial]
# [START import_module]
from datetime import timedelta
from textwrap import dedent

# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG

# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

# [END import_module]

# [START default_args]
# These args will get passed on to each operator
# You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
    #'depends_on_past': False,
    #'email': ['courtney.poles@alteryx.com'],
    #'email_on_failure': False,
    #'email_on_retry': False,
    #'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
    # 'wait_for_downstream': False,
    # 'dag': dag,
    # 'sla': timedelta(hours=2),
    # 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300),
    # 'on_failure_callback': some_function,
    # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function,
    # 'on_retry_callback': another_function,
    # 'sla_miss_callback': yet_another_function,
    # 'trigger_rule': 'all_success'
}
# [END default_args]

# [START instantiate_dag]
with DAG(
    'baton',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A sample Airflow DAG that runs one in and one out of process job.',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['baton_example'],
) as dag:
    # [END instantiate_dag]

    # t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
    # [START basic_task]
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='in_process_job',
        bash_command='python /opt/airflow/dags/scripts/baton_in_process.py',
        #retries=1
    )

    #t2 = BashOperator(
        #task_id='oop_job',
        #bash_command=r'python opt\airflow\scripts\test.py',
        #retries=1,
    #)

    t1 #>> t2

    # [END basic_task]

    # [START documentation]
    # t1.doc_md = dedent(
    #     """\
    # #### Task Documentation
    # You can document your task using the attributes `doc_md` (markdown),
    # `doc` (plain text), `doc_rst`, `doc_json`, `doc_yaml` which gets
    # rendered in the UI's Task Instance Details page.
    # ![img](http://montcs.bloomu.edu/~bobmon/Semesters/2012-01/491/import%20soul.png)
    #
    # """
    # )
    #
    # dag.doc_md = __doc__  # providing that you have a docstring at the beggining of the DAG
    # dag.doc_md = """
    # This is a documentation placed anywhere
    # """  # otherwise, type it like this
    # [END documentation]

    # [START jinja_template]
    # templated_command = dedent(
    #     """
    # {% for i in range(5) %}
    #     echo "{{ ds }}"
    #     echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
    #     echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
    # {% endfor %}
    # """
    # )

    # t3 = BashOperator(
    #     task_id='templated',
    #     depends_on_past=False,
    #     bash_command=templated_command,
    #     params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in'},
    # )
    # [END jinja_template]


# [END tutorial]
```

My Log File

```
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,061] {taskinstance.py:876} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: baton.in_process_job 2021-07-07T18:59:40.183659+00:00 [None]>
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,069] {taskinstance.py:876} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: baton.in_process_job 2021-07-07T18:59:40.183659+00:00 [None]>
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,069] {taskinstance.py:1067} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,070] {taskinstance.py:1068} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,074] {taskinstance.py:1069} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,090] {taskinstance.py:1087} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): in_process_job> on 2021-07-07T18:59:40.183659+00:00
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,096] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 1302 to run task
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,099] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'baton', 'in_process_job', '2021-07-07T18:59:40.183659+00:00', '--job-id', '139', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/baton_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpmew1_wqd', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp9qfruch0']
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,100] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 139: Subtask in_process_job
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,135] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: baton.in_process_job 2021-07-07T18:59:40.183659+00:00 [running]> on host 665b4e46f1a2
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,177] {taskinstance.py:1282} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=baton
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=in_process_job
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-07-07T18:59:40.183659+00:00
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,178] {subprocess.py:52} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,179] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'python /opt/***/dags/scripts/baton_in_process.py']
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,187] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Output:
[2021-07-07 18:59:44,383] {subprocess.py:79} INFO - ('Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJYbW9zWUpINjNNZktBZzdtOW05cWR2QVV2eHJ4OGQyektZekczYmpXLWtBIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2MjU2ODQ0NDQsImlhdCI6MTYyNTY4NDM4NCwianRpIjoiNGVjZDQ4NjAtYjQwNS00OWYxLTg4YjgtZDJhOGI5NmI4ZWM0IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjVkYjc4YTE4LWUzMWUtNDdlNy1hMjFiLWQ0ZWE3NDZjZDAwNCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI0MzdlMjNlYS1lODlmLTQzYWYtOWVjNS00YjlkZjkyOGVmZmQiLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwic2NvcGUiOiJwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.MLmSdu0oaFEJPv74uprZFszHD9PF0Y20LmwBhUZjRIRb9pg164mGTXsVf1wdzHZa9M6GjBE7azrfPFvX9A-bRN9BW7Ah7QGUprf20hCHktEPFk3_B_IHJBzsMo6cb6lJ1DcFKZR2mG6nVWxsAy8zVITmJbhcdlcA8cWYl7xbom6knrfNCBwvG7zeJHpHwl04mQVUtUCvwH13l0D_LoDGhUTRALdwTz3aeNnVzQ_KdLmUceU8pPUMaccm7L0o3AkY0YqGq08oLAI9ve3vOqCkMgBl8XTaEWEgzPxJOysPmUz6nOvCY6TqEJj90Mv0Mw2J-VrU4O7kkCtX_quTAUU6TA', {'returncode': 0, 'stdout': '  % Total    
[2021-07-07 18:59:45,131] {subprocess.py:79} INFO - job posted
[2021-07-07 18:59:45,132] {subprocess.py:79} INFO - {'returncode': 0, 'stdout': '* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x555826d09fb0)\n* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x555826d09fb0)\n  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\n  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x555826d09fb0)\n* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x555826d09fb0)\n*   Trying 172.18.0.6...\n* TCP_NODELAY set\n* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x555826d09fb0)\n* Connected to server (172.18.0.6) port 8080 (#0)\n> GET /v1/s/master/jobs/e55db103-f196-4566-8eed-5db5c02c85ab HTTP/1.1\n> Host: server:8080\n> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0\n> Accept: */*\n> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJYbW9zWUpINjNNZktBZzdtOW05cWR2QVV2eHJ4OGQyektZekczYmpXLWtBIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2MjU2ODQ0NDUsImlhdCI6MTYyNTY4NDM4NSwianRpIjoiZWU1NGE2M2EtOGViYy00MGFjLTg0NjktNzc1YjRjODU2ZWEyIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjVkYjc4YTE4LWUzMWUtNDdlNy1hMjFiLWQ0ZWE3NDZjZDAwNCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiJiOTkzNGZjZS1hMmYwLTQ4MzMtOTM4OC0wMmIzYWRiMTYzMjEiLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwic2NvcGUiOiJwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.FevvIr6HDTIDsgYby3kn-LZgNxzgRba6Hjn9pK4f1Bxxnx0tkSjz1uEUXLAz0uoJVPdMqzQhvBicTfZK3u8wyhhWebx6nTGi8meGW4Ue1QviBHK7Jf7jfUCPgqvJwKQcpdBczMEENck_g0O9oMPgsLkOk0GAeeqnXfzht_Wm_5uxanfLFOVrpU657JUfVt6FWZuzhnp4RXSeLDviy54Qgv9kBWtAzeT4fp-AlzsyEGUCAGy4tPjRC5F8zbFAQq2vSWmsLVCgNm2epI67yqN5zF5iZMChkigFv3y9AQB3IeBV4W0fOIqRINuu9OPBRCAU72DbgTNOBV76Pu3KmVo9_A\n> \n< HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n< Server: akka-http/10.2.3\n< Date: Wed, 07 Jul 2021 18:59:45 GMT\n< Content-Type: application/json\n< Content-Length: 1385\n< \n{ [1385 bytes data]\n\n100  1385  100  1385    0     0  38472      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 38472\n* Connection #0 to host server left intact\n', 'stderr': None} job_status: completed
[2021-07-07 18:59:45,144] {subprocess.py:83} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2021-07-07 18:59:45,200] {taskinstance.py:1191} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=baton, task_id=in_process_job, execution_date=20210707T185940, start_date=20210707T185944, end_date=20210707T185945
[2021-07-07 18:59:45,277] {local_task_job.py:151} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error once I triggered the DAG to run in the UI. From there I was able to clear the schedules for each task and successfully execute each one individually.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Can you elaborate your answer? Also do you have an idea why this happens? What airflow version are you using?